# How can i get the method name of the transaction from transaction hash?

Tags: web3js

```
allLogs.forEach((log) => {
      web3.eth.getTransaction(log.transactionHash, function (err, result) {
        if (result.value) {
          console.log(result);
          console.log(
            "Transaction value : " +
              web3.utils.fromWei(result.value, "ether") +
              " ETH"
          );
          console.log("Method" + result.input.substr(0, 10));
          console.log("ascii " + web3.utils.hexToString(result.input));
          const data = {
            from: result.from,
            to: result.to,
            value: web3.utils.fromWei(result.value, "ether"),
          };
          allTransactionsData.push(data);
        }
      });
    });
```

Here the error occurs:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid continuation byte
    at readContinuationByte (utf8.js:115:1)
    at decodeSymbol (utf8.js:155:1)
    at Object.utf8decode [as decode] (utf8.js:190:1)
    at Object.hexToUtf8 (utils.js:191:1)
    at Object.callback (useRecentTransaction.jsx:72:1)
    at sendTxCallback (index.js:546:1)
    at cb (util.js:689:1)
    at push../node_modules/process/browser.js.Item.run (browser.js:153:1)
    at drainQueue (browser.js:123:1)
```